# How polite does this construction sound: "Шли бы вы куда еще?"

Tags: словоупотребление, значения

> **Шли бы вы** куда еще, а?

```
Imperfective Past + "бы" + Subject
```

Given the presence of "бы" accompanied by the *conditional* past, is it close to:

> If you guys could go somewhere else, hum?

---

Incidentally, how does the perfective version differ in meaning?

> **Пошли бы вы** куда еще, а?

```
Perfective Past + "бы" + Subject
```

Comment: It's not polite at all. To me there is no special difference between two of them but the first sounds more natural.

Comment: @demonplus the second would sound more natural with negation. "А не пойти бы вам...." & "А не пошёл бы ты...". Some pseudo-polite language, kind of "Would you not kindly fuck yourself?"

Comment: @Arioch Agree about natural but this is also not polite :)

Comment: @demonplus Still not polite enough for you??? Would not you kindly... :-D :-P  /// on a serious note, with negation the phrase becomes a bit softer. Not really much softened, but somewhat.

Comment: please let me refer you to a response to a question about a similar construct [А не пошло бы оно всё на...?](https://russian.stackexchange.com/a/16046/7674)

Comment: Basically, it is a Russian version of "GTFO".

Comment: As a Russian, I've never heard the phrase in this form in Russian. It would sound more weird than insulting. You should use a negation, like indicated by Arioch and SergeySlepov in their answers.

Answer (score 2):

Both sentences are insults phrased as 'polite' requests. The conditional version is normally more polite which makes it sound even more oxymoronic.

A common Russian insult is telling someone to go f*ck themselves (иди на х*й!) with numerous euphemisms for х*й including: лесом, в баню, куда подальше, куда еще, etc.

The imperative иди can be replaced by an even more rude пошёл or softened to a conditional negated form А не пойти бы вам... making the whole phrase sound 'polite' bit still insulting. This form was often used by intelligentsia.

Comment: Hi. How does "**А не пойти бы вам ...**" differ in tone from "**Почему бы вам не пойти ...**"?

Comment: сами фразы _Шли бы вы куда еще, а?_ или _Почему бы вам не пойти куда-нибудь?_ даже без отсылок к известному оскорблению подразумевают, что _я останусь, а вы куда-то уйдёте, и мне не важно куда, т.е. я просто не хочу с вами общаться_, что само по себе довольно оскорбительно. А если в конструкцию добавить что-нибудь конкретное _Почему бы вам не пойти в кино?_, то фраза становится абсолютно нормальной.

Comment: @yalov Скорее тогда "почему бы ТЕБЕ не пойти в кино?". Вежливое "вы" подразумевает дистанцию между чужими людьми, и тогда такой совет обычно (не всегда, но часто) будет звучать неестественно фамильярно.